# How can I create a table with a unique name and then insert data from another table into that table, preferably using a single trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, insert

I want to have an empty table, when someone inserts data into it, I then want that table to be immediately copied to a unique table name and then the original table truncated in readiness for the same thing to happen again.

I've tried doing this with a trigger that then executes a procedure, and I've tried just doing this with a trigger only and I get issues with both.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER REPLICATE_PDU_TABLE
AFTER INSERT ON PDU 
DECLARE V_TABLENAME VARCHAR2(30) := 'PDU_IN_PROGRESS_ || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDDHHMISS');
CURSOR C1 IS
SELECT * FROM PDU;
V_PDU C1%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE ' || V_TABLENAME || ' AS SELECT * FROM PDU';
OPEN C1;
FETCH C1 INTO PDU ;
CLOSE C1;
INSERT INTO V_TABLENAME
VALUES (
V_PDU.TARGETSCHEMA,
V_PDU.PRODUCTIONSCHEMA,
V_PDU.PRODUCTIONDATABASE,
V_PDU.TABLE_NAME,
V_PDU.DRIVER_TABLE,
V_PDU.MANDATORY_JOIN,
V_PDU.ADDITIONAL_JOINS,
V_PDU.TABLE_COMPRESSION);
END TRIGGER REPLICATE_PDU_TABLE;
```

This "May" actually work, but I can't the trigger to compile because "INSERT INTO V_TABLENAME" won't work, as the table does not yet exist. This is the first part of my code, create a unique table, copy all of the data from the original table into it, upon insert.

Comment: In my opinion, this is a wrong approach. You'll end up with a *zillion* tables whose name have a timestamp. How do you plan to do anything with them? How will you access data within? If the process requires two tables, consider using a global temporary table (GTT) using *on commit delete rows* option as the first point of insert. Once it is done, move data to a target table which would contain additional DATE datatype column (so that you'd know *when* you inserted those values). COMMIT would a) save data in the target table, b) release GTT.

Comment: @Littlefoot Are you suggesting that I create the GTT in a trigger, and then within that trigger use a CTAS statement based on the GTT to populate a new table from the GTT? I'm not sure how to use the GTT to help move forward.

Comment: No! Don't create anything in a trigger (or any other PL/SQL procedure). In Oracle, we create tables once and use them many times. (As far as I've heard, MS SQL Server works differently - they create tables all the time). So. create all tables you need, GTT included. Load data into it. Once loading is done, insert data into the target table - **one** target table. Don't use triggers at all.

Comment: @Littlefoot How do you insert data from one "master table" that a user just inserted into, without a trigger?

Comment: In a brand new transaction, Dave.

Comment: @Littlefoot Yeah, but something needs to um... "Trigger" that transaction. Even if I create a procedure to copy data from one table to another once the master table is popuated (Which I have done) using a trigger to fire the procedure means it fires before the data is inserted in the table. So, my procedure fires, creates a copy table and then, nothing. The table is empty because the master hasn't had its data committed yet. So, I can see why triggers are of no use. I can't see how else to do it though. I need a means of creating a new table, and populating it automatically.

Comment: What I meant was: you said that someone inserts data into a table. How is it done? If it is some kind of a *loading application* (written in Oracle Forms or Apex or ...), a "brand new transaction" would be yet another *push a button* which would "trigger" copying data from that temporary table into another one. If it is a command prompt program, it has its flow - it loads, loads, loads, ... and - once there's nothing else to load, then copy everything you have into another table.

Comment: Yeah, it's loaded through Apex...and then that's the end of the transaction. All I wanna do is just copy that table data into another table as soon as the Apex transaction is complete. Like I said, I thought a trigger would do it, or, a trigger that executes a procedure to do it but any approach of that nature means the copy table has no data. The only other way I can think of, is just have a job that does a count(*) on the table every 5 secs and then if it finds data, it does executes the procedure I wrote to copy the table. I can't see how else I can do it.

Comment: Apex' loading takes several pages to complete, right? On the last page, there's the FINISH button. Instead of its default action (which is .. what? Redirection to the starting page?), create a **process* which would perform copying data from temporary table to the target table. Also, create a branch which takes place when FINISH button is pressed, and let it do the redirection to another page.

Comment: I'm not great with Apex tbh... I was hoping I could do this at the back end. Wondered if you may have any ideas in terms of a PL/SQL process to do it? Thanks for your help and ideas.

Comment: That process would be (in its simplest form) `insert into target_table select * from source_table`, but I'd suggest you to name all columns involved.

Comment: In terms of what causes that process to spring into action though, having ruled out a trigger, is a job checking if the table is populated every x amount of seconds the only way forward in terms of a back end process?

Comment: I was talking about the Apex process. A scheduled process ("every x seconds") would work, probably, but you don't have any control over it, i.e. you'd have to code *something* to let you know that there was an error which prevented copying. As job runs in the database, you can't just *display* it on the screen but send mail, populate some log table (and have someone monitor it), etc. In my opinion, Apex process is the simplest option.

Answer (score 2):

This is really not the sort of thing we should do in a trigger. There's some complicated processing which is tricky to manage. For instance, what should happen in you can't create a trigger? Or if the truncation fails?

This is compounded by the prohibition on issuing commits in triggers. All DDL statements issue commits (two per statement) so the only way to fire DDL statements  from a trigger is to use the `autonomous_transaction` pragma. This is is a nested transaction, which means it cannot see the current contents of the table. So the whole thing is a bit messy.

Here is a thought experiment which illustrates the sort of thing you would need to do:

```
create or replace trigger replicate_pdu_table
    after insert on pdu 
declare 
    -- note use the twenty-hour clock in mask
    v_tablename varchar2(30) := 'PDU_IN_PROGRESS_' || to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS');
    procedure create_table is
        pragma autonomous_transaction;
    begin
        execute immediate 'create table ' || v_tablename || ' as select * from pdu where 1=2';
    end create_table;
    procedure truncate_pdu is
        pragma autonomous_transaction;
    begin
        execute immediate 'truncate table pdu';
    end truncate_pdu;
begin 
    create_table;
    execute immediate 'insert into ' || v_tablename || ' select * from pdu';
    truncate_pdu;
end;
/
```

The problem is the truncation: it hurls

```
ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired
```

The reason being the trigger fires when we insert rows into `pdu`. That is, before we can issue a commit. Consequently the main session has a lock on `pdu` so the autonomous transaction can't do the truncate. This is an absolute blocker to the use of a trigger: you need to run this as a procedure, perhaps called from a polling job or via a queue.

---

The wider question is, why are you doing this? **A transactional approach which creates tables on the fly is always a smell**. Apart from the proliferation of itty-bitty cluttering the schema there are the risks of failure which I mentioned in the intro. Also, how will the processes consuming the created table know its name???? Your entire process will be built out of dynamic SQL. This is a maintenance and support nightmare.

Without knowing the details of what you're trying to achieve it's not possible to suggest a better approach. But be assured, there are definitely better approaches available to you.

Comment: So can I changed it so that an insert into another table is done once the initial copy is completed, with a "Y" for example and that table has a trigger which when updated will execute a procedure to delete / truncate the original table?

Answer (score 1):

Execute insert statement also using execute immediate command as shown below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER REPLICATE_PDU_TABLE
AFTER INSERT ON PDU 
DECLARE V_TABLENAME VARCHAR2(30) := 'PDU_IN_PROGRESS_ || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDDHHMISS');
CURSOR C1 IS
SELECT * FROM PDU;
V_PDU C1%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE ' || V_TABLENAME || ' AS SELECT * FROM PDU';
OPEN C1;
FETCH C1 INTO v_PDU ;
CLOSE C1;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
INSERT INTO '|| V_TABLENAME || '
VALUES ( '||
V_PDU.TARGETSCHEMA ||','||
V_PDU.PRODUCTIONSCHEMA ||','||
V_PDU.PRODUCTIONDATABASE ||','||
V_PDU.TABLE_NAME ||','||
V_PDU.DRIVER_TABLE ||','||
V_PDU.MANDATORY_JOIN||','||
V_PDU.ADDITIONAL_JOINS ||','||
V_PDU.TABLE_COMPRESSION ||')';
END TRIGGER REPLICATE_PDU_TABLE;
```

You can also check the following link to learn how to use execute immediate statement.
[Execute Immediate Example](https://www.vinish.ai/how-to-truncate-table-in-oracle-procedure)

Comment: Just looking at this now... thanks! The reason I'm doing it is... - I want people to enter data into a front end form... - which will "Really" be the PDU table. People will do this maybe 4 times a day. I want the data put away somewhere to be processed, which will take maybe 2-3 hrs and after that it can be archived never to be used again (most likely) the main thing is to just get it out if the way once the form gets filled in and I have the data.

Comment: I think only this much part is enough to do the task. Insert into would be the repetitive action. CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER REPLICATE_PDU_TABLE
AFTER INSERT ON PDU 
DECLARE V_TABLENAME VARCHAR2(30) := 'PDU_IN_PROGRESS_ || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDDHHMISS');
CURSOR C1 IS
SELECT * FROM PDU;
V_PDU C1%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE ' || V_TABLENAME || ' AS SELECT * FROM PDU';

Comment: @VinishKapoor - have you tried creating a table from a trigger? Did work?